# Можно ли использовать словосочетание "сделать экологию карьерой"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов

У меня с коллегами возник вопрос: а можно ли использовать такое словосочетание: "сделать экологию карьерой"?

В тексте: "Для тех, кто хочет сделать экологию карьерой, а не только хобби!"

Answer (score 1):

Слово "карьера" в современном русском языке не употребляется в значении профессии или рода занятий (словари такое значение приводят как устаревшее; видимо, в первое время после заимствования было иначе), обычно оно указывает на достижения в *должностном росте*, соответствующих полномочиях столоначальника и т. п. Поэтому протипопоставление *хобби и карьеры* выглядит не вполне естественным (как предложение "разжиться" за счёт экологии), как неуклюжий перевод с другого языка. Выражение же "**а не только**" означает, что одновременно предлагается оставить себе и такое хобби. Лучше было бы "... ***своей* профессией, а не *просто* хобби!**".

Answer (score 0):

Слово *карьера* употреблено неверно, смысл фразы неясен.

Кроме того, что предложил Alex_аnder, можно предположить, что имелось в виду следующее:

**Не только для тех, для кого экология — хобби, но и для тех, кто хочет сделать ее своей профессией!**

Или так:

**Не только для тех, для кого экология — хобби, но и для тех, кто хочет сделать карьеру в этой области!**